# ERROR: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found

Tags: linux

I've been having this problem for a month now and everyday I try to fix it, but nothing works.

ANY program that uses libstdc++ throws this error.
Im on Kali linux, i do have it installed(apt-get install libstdc++6). the programs that need it build and install fine but running them gives this error.

Ive tried re-installing, deleting, adding repo's, building from sources, changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH, even editing the makefiles of the programs and static linking it, redirecting sym links, pretty much everything you can find on google about this demon of an error.

the one thing i have not tried is a fresh install of kali, and im trying my best not to do to that.

UPDATE:

I decided to bite the bullet and reinstall the latest version of kali. Good great. install it and all. and guess what! it doesn't even wanna apt-get update! like its broken... gives errors like Hash mismatch (on offical kali rolling repos), you have held broken packages. ive tried everything again from (and i know this was a bad idea) editing the sources.list (adding kali sana repos), multiple apt-get commands (apt-get -f install, apt-get autoremove, apt-get autoclean, apt-get --fix-broken etc...) even when i was installing kali when configuring apt it gave errors. Im dieing of errors. thinking of moving over to ubuntu.

Comment: Does this give you any clues?  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213025  - If I do `locate libstdc` to find it, then `strings /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -i glibc` I get a bunch of responses, that don't include GLIBCXX_3.4.22 - maybe there's a newer version of libstdc++ than what's in your Kali distro software repository? (turns out my libstdc++.so.6 is a symlink to libstdc++.so.6.0.19 ).  Or might be worth trying to get a newer version from some other repo - debian stretch uses 6.1.1-11 https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libstdc++6 which may be late enough

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for Kali Linux, but it works for me on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
```

You can check if you get GLIBCXX required version with this:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6` is asking to upgrade everything for my system. It is not good.

Comment: There is no issue in updating your system. You should update your system regularly, to have security fixes and have latest features for your system.

Comment: Well, I don't like to update everything since some new libs could not work well with my computer. For example, some time ago an updating disabled my wifi and I had to run some module by hand to recognize the device.